# как объединить два APIView класса в DRF, с разными сериализаторами

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

как вывести данные разных функций представления и разных сериализаторов на одной странице

views.py

```
class UserCoursesAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AccountCoursesSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        course_slug = self.kwargs.get('course_slug')
        return Courses.objects.filter(slug=course_slug)

    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        course_slug = self.kwargs.get('course_slug')
        course = get_object_or_404(Courses, slug=course_slug)
        return Videos.objects.filter(course_id=course.pk)
```

serializers.py

```
class AccountCoursesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Courses
        fields = ['name', 'information']

class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Videos
        fields = ['video']
```